# Vue router hot reload not working when lazy loading in router in a typescript project

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, vue-router

I'm new to vue and building my first app. I was following a tutorial and noticed a way to lazy load in the router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import MainContent from '@/layout/main-content.vue'
import Home from '@/views/home.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
     {
       path: '/',
       component: MainContent,
       children: [
          {
             path: ''
             //This works
             component: Home
             //This doesn't work
             component: () => import('@/views/home.vue')
          },
          {
             path: 'home'
             //This works
             component: Home
             //This doesn't work
             component: () => import('@/views/home.vue')
          }
       ]
     }
  ]
})
```

You can see in the above example, I'm showing the synchronous way and the asynchronous way. There are two paths to the home component because I need to be able to support the root '/' and the '/home' as the default. That's not the issue because it works the synchronous way (plus, I tried it with other child routes).

The strange thing is when I lazy load, the page doesn't refresh (hot load) until I inspect using the browser tool. Even when I force a refresh in the browser, it doesn't appear. When I open the inspector, then I see the home component in the browser. Why would I only see the Home component when I open the inspector?

Comment: Hot reloads work flawlessly with dynamic imports for me. Possibly something to do with browser cache?

Comment: @MarcRo is there anything else you need to do other than the code I provided above? The issue is screen refresh. Because when I open the inspector and hover over the elements that are supposed to be show, I then see them. The problem is that I don't see that after changing routes.

Comment: Can you check in your browser tools whether the component bundles are downloaded?

Comment: @MarcRo Yup, I definitely see the component file come down when I change the route. It's just not rendering on the screen unless I hover over the element in the tools.

Comment: Could it be some issue in the component? If Vue devtools register it, the Vue instance should load correctly..

Comment: @MarcRo I figured out it was the vue dev tools. I uninstalled the extension and the problem went away. I then reinstalled the extension and the problem is back. Doh!

Comment: Glad you had some progress! But I am rather convinced that the problem lies within your code and is not with the dev tools!